# Vector out of range on a specific machine?

Tags: c++, vector

I've got a function in one of my programs that is throwing an error on only on a particular machine. It runs fine on my Windows box, but when I test it out on a Linux machine it throws a vector out of range error:

```
----------------------------------------------
          FINDING LONGEST WORD CHAIN
----------------------------------------------
The longest chain(s) are:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check
Abort
```

This is what my routine looks like:

```
void findLongestChain(vector<FlexArray<StringWrap>* >& chains) {
    int max;
    int maxIndex;
    vector<int> v;

    for(std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i != chains.size(); i++) { // iterate through vector
        int chainSize = getChainSize(chains, i);

        if(chainSize == max) { // just in case we have a tie
            v.push_back(i);
        }

        else if(chainSize > max) { // we have found a larger word chain breaking any previous ties
            max = chainSize;
            maxIndex = i;
            v.clear();
            v.push_back(i); 
        }
    }

    cout << "----------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "          FINDING LONGEST WORD CHAIN          " << endl;
    cout << "----------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "The longest chain(s) are: " << endl;

    for(std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {

        cout << "    Chain #" << v[i] << ": " << getWordChain( chains, v[i] ) << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Each chain(s) contain " << getChainSize(chains, maxIndex) << " total words.";
}
```

Anyways, I've never seen this happen before. I was wondering if anyone had some general tips/advice/experience with program errors on different machines and how to go about approaching a solution to the problem.

Comment: It looks like the error is happening inside `getWordChain`. Can you show that method?

Comment: gdb will tell you where this exception was thrown. You don't provide the source for `getChainSize()` and `getWordChain()`, it might be there also.

Comment: Also, does it break on **every** Linux machine, or just on one particular one that you have tried?

Comment: Your `max` is uninitialized.

Comment: It happens on only this one linux machine. Let me try your suggestion Eric.

Comment: There will be a vector out of bounds access on both machines, but one of them is going silently unnoticed.  If you change all of your `[]` accesses to `.at()` then both will behave the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following lines are probably the culprits.

```
int max;
int maxIndex;
```

The variables are not initialized. Try initializing them to something sensible and see how things go.

Comment: This fixed it! Why does not initializing the variables cause issues?

Comment: @Bob Uninitialized variables can have any value. You can't count on any predictable behavior. If some machines initialize them to `0`, it's just lucky coincidence.

Comment: @Bob, I guess your uninitialized `max` and `maxIndex` happens to have a very big value on your linux machine so that none of the two loops effectively run. And the error is in `getChainSize(chains, maxIndex)` where you access the vector via `maxIndex`. Just my guess;)

Comment: Thanks guys -- this all makes perfect sense. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @Bob Technically it is undefined behaviour to read from an uninitialized variable. Cranking up the warning levels on GCC gives a useful warning: `warning: 'i' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]`. Clang produces a similar one.